# How to wait for completion handler in AppDelegate in React-Native JS

Tags: ios, react-native

I’m quite new to React-Native and I can’t find the solution to this despite a lot of searching.

I have a completion handler that gets run asynchronously in my AppDelegate’s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Question: How do I wait for its execution to complete before showing the root `React.Component`?

Needless to say, the completion handler sets important info at the start, without which the app cannot function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use a native iOS module with a promise: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios